# Creating line with different Colors and a displaying score above that in swiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, swiftui

I want to create a UI like this in SwiftUI. I tried using path and geometryReader but I can't find the proper solution.

[image: picture showing UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```swift
struct ProbabilityView: View {
    var title: String
    var value: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
            
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Color.green
                        Color.yellow
                        Color.red
                    }
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .frame(maxHeight: 16)
                    
                    Text(formatted)
                        .font(.callout)
                        .padding(.vertical, 3)
                        .frame(width: 52)
                        .background(Color(.systemBackground))
                        .cornerRadius(16)
                        .shadow(radius: 8)
                        // Substract the width of the bubble
                        .offset(x: (proxy.size.width - 52) * value)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
            .animation(.default, value: value)
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
    }
    
    var formatted: String {
        let value = self.value * 100
        return "\(Int(value.rounded())) %"
    }
}
```

Demo

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                ProbabilityView(title: "Virus probability score", value: value)
            }
            
            Section {
                Button {
                    value = 0
                } label: {
                    Text("0%")
                }
                
                Button {
                    value = 0.5
                } label: {
                    Text("50%")
                }
                
                Button {
                    value = 1.0
                } label: {
                    Text("100%")
                }
                
                Button {
                    value = Double.random(in: 0...1)
                } label: {
                    Text("Random")
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
    }
}
```